# Problem with power sets of power sets question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The example I am trying to work on is:

If $a \in X$ then $P(a) \in P(P(\cup X))$

I've tried writing out what it would mean to be an element of $P(P(\cup X))$, but it's not really going anywhere.

Thank you for any help

Comment: forget the $\cup X$ for now and figure out what it means to be in a powerset of a  powerset maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notation can sometimes be distracting. The remedy is more notation. Let $u=P(a).$ Let $w=\cup X.$ Let $v=P(w)=P(\cup X).$ Then $$(i)\quad P(a)\in P(P(\cup X))\iff u\in P(v)\iff$$ $$(ii)\quad \iff  u\subset v \iff P(a)\subset P(w)\iff$$ $$(iii)\quad \iff \forall b\;(b\subset a\implies b\subset w)\iff$$ $$(iv)\quad \iff a\subset w\iff$$ $$(v)\quad \iff a\subset \cup X.$$ And we do have $a\in X\implies a\subset \cup X$ from the def'n of $\cup X.$

BTW. The step from $(iii)$ to $(iv)$ should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

When does $\mathcal P(a)\in\mathcal P(b)$?

Well, $\mathcal P(a)$ is all the subsets of $a$. So It means that $\mathcal P(a)$ is itself a subset of $b$.

But here we have that $b$ itself is $\mathcal P(c)$. So what does it mean that $\mathcal P(a)\subseteq\mathcal P(c)$?

Once you figure out this answer, you should be able to figure out how to prove the full statement by noting that $\bigcup X=\{x\mid\exists Y\in X: x\in Y\}$, which implies that if $Y\in X$, then $Y\subseteq\bigcup X$.